# UITableView Detail View controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have table view in my split view app i want that for each i have different view controller for. eg one row i have cal and other is computer etc so for both these i may have different views and on clicking on them i may get the desired view

i have done following code for table view in split view

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section        {
GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers   objectAtIndex:section];
return sectionController.numberOfRow;
  }

  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers    objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
     return [sectionController cellForRow:indexPath.row];
       }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath {


     GCRetractableSectionController* sectionController = [self.retractableControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath   viewController:detailViewController withData:@""];
       }
      else {
       return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath viewController:detailViewController withData:[generalCalculatorArray   objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1]];
       }
    }
     else if(indexPath.section == 1){
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
    return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath viewController:detailViewController withData:@""];
    }
      else {
       return [sectionController didSelectCellAtRow:indexPath viewController:detailViewController withData:[cardiologyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row -  1]];
     }

  }
 }
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: what happens when you run it as is?

Comment: it displays the same text of cell on detail view controller so how can give every cell with separate view controller

Comment: Kory Sharp question is that i want separate detail view for each cell becuase data for each cell is with a lot of difference in detail view

Comment: You probably want to read the UITableViewController programming guide. It seems like you might be confused about the mechanism used to display detail content when a cell is selected. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: I know ho to dipslay in detail but i want that for e.g i have 3 cells apple ,mango,orange so for all three i want three different detail view controllers so how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Apple has the example of what you are looking for,  [Here You Go](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MultipleDetailViews/Introduction/Intro.html) or you just need to know precisely 
then continue reading 

 `NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationController, detailViewController, nil];` 

where the **detailViewController** in above line represent the instance of your detail view controller you want to change. While changing Detail view cont, it's necessary to **Update the split view controller's view controllers array** 

`splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;`

   `[viewControllers release];`

Hope this helps you. If not raise comment please.